# Multiple web apps in Tomcat( using same jars ) leads to perm gen OOM

Tags: java, tomcat

I am running a Tomcat with two web app instances, the development of the two apps are independent. When I start the tomcat server, and start accessing the applications, it either throws a Perm Gen OOM Exception or a Heap Space OOM Exception. Both these apps use same jars, these jars are bundled inside the respective lib folders of the webapps. Is the perm gen caused because of the repeated loading of the classes? How can I avoid the Perm Gen and Heap space exceptions?

EDIT: I want the best practices to be followed at this scenario. Please advise on the same.

Note: I run the tomcat on a 2008 Server with 12 gb ram. the server also hosts other tomcat servers and a MSSQL server for the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the -XX:PermSize -XX:MaxPermSize size to avoid the issue in the configuration file of the tomcat. Ideally it will be 256, Just increase it to 512.

Answer (score 0):

Such errors can certainly be caused by memory leaks caused by class loader memory leaks (https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection).

You can try increasing permgen space (`-XX:PermSize<size> -XX:MaxPermSize<size>`) and see if it helps. If it just decreases the frequency of OOMs, then you, most likely, have a memory leaks. Unfortnuatelly, finding the solution is not easy. I avoid this by restarting tomcat on application redeployment, a strategy that may or may not work for you.